# For one way missions to any planet is it planned to pay astronauts?

Tags: colonization, future-missions, exoplanet

As one way missions astronauts would never come back (because it's a real one way mission with a many years trip), is it planed to pay them or giving them enough hardware, tools, food is their salary ? Has this subject ever been considered in plans to send a one way mission to any planet without return ?

Comment: The question appeals to me -but  I would try it over on [WorldBuilding Stack](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No I'm happy with the answer I got here. I was not looking for exotic or sci-fi  answer but for one as close as possible as what would a space agency can think about today.

Comment: So you go to a new world, received free technology and knowledge to begin a colony which is going to rule the whole planet and you say it's us who should pay YOU? Sorry, this means you failed the mental sanity test and your astronaut contract is hereby terminated :-)

Comment: @Everyone The question as it stands would very likely be considered off topic on Worldbuilding; Worldbuilding's scope *specifically excludes* questions about the real world. See https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. This could probably be rewritten into a form that would be acceptable there; for example, by focusing on how, given some constraints, an offworld economy could be bootstrapped. But that's not where it is right now.

Comment: I explicitly asked it to be linked to the real world, I'm not looking for speculation:)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they would, for a couple of reasons:

1. The money might be little good to them most of the time, but they might have family on Earth that could benefit from it.
2. If they have a successful long term colony, they would need the money to purchase goods back on Earth.

I suspect it would be similar to how the first colonies in the America's were, which was more of a barter type system, where everyone earned a portion of the goods. Wikipedia talks a great deal about how money functioned in the [early American settlements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_American_currency).

> There were three general types of money in the colonies of British America: specie (coins), paper money and commodity money.

Commodity money, it goes on to explain, was using commodities for money. They had their own coins, distinct from the British coins, but they could be used somewhat interchangeably. However, this might not be required for Mars, as they will likely be more concerned about digital money, and might have very little need of physical cash.

[The Case for Mars](http://amzn.to/23utJit) speculates that people will move to Mars because they will earn higher salaries there, which will allow them to bring their families over, similar to what was done in the early colonization days.

Comment: Oh I assumed that people who would go for a one way mission would have no family they know and would have no easy way to come back in they're lifetime. One way, for me, meant never come back ever.

Comment: I added a bit more on that subject, basically, one person might go to pave the way for their family to go in the future.